# Unable to install the Cloudinary Integration module

Tags: 7

I downloaded the [Cloudinary Integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/cloudinary) module and installed it.

The module appears in the module list, but I cannot enable it. The modules page shows this message after the description of the module.

> Requires: Cloudinary Stream Wrapper (disabled), Cloudinary SDK (disabled), Libraries (missing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't installed the dependencies.

They're listed on the module page:

> **Requirements**
>
> - Libraries
> - Cloudinary SDK for PHP
> - Cloudinary API Account

Download each of those as well, then try again.

Comment: where to put those folders?

Comment: They're all modules - same place as you put the other one

Comment: I kept those libraries, cloudinary, cloudinary php master folders in Myproject/sites/all/modules.. Is that correct? Still there are some errors  in Myproject/admin/config/media/cloudinary.  *"Please make sure the Cloudinary SDK library is installed in the libraries directory.
The Cloudinary SDK for PHP library could not be found."*